# Telegram Bot API: Is it possible to force collapse the default keyboard on mobile?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Telegram Bot API manual says that when you remove a custom keyboard, the default letter keyboard will be displayed. 
I was wondering if there was a way to suppress the latter.
I don't want it to cover up half the screen and unnecessarily obstruct the view when I don't need it there.